# .NET Core - Force download file on API call

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to force download a file for a client once they click on a button.

I have tried multiple suggestions from previous answers none of which force a download but instead it sends back a link for user to click.

[image]

```
[HttpPost("DownloadDocumentFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile([FromBody] Dictionary<string, Guid> parameters)
{
    parameters.TryGetValue("FileId", out var fileId);

    var fileContentResult =  await Mediator.Send(new CloudFileRetrieve.Command
            {
                FileId = fileId
            });

    string contentDisposition = $"attachment; filename={fileContentResult.FileDownloadName}";

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);

    //    new ContentDisposition
    //{
    //    //FileName = x.FileDownloadName,
    //    //Inline = false, // Set to false to force download
    //}.ToString()); // does nothing special 

    return fileContentResult; // Generates link
    //return File(fileContentResult.FileContents, "application/octet-stream", fileContentResult.FileDownloadName); // Generates link
    //return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(x.FileContents), x.ContentType) ;// Generates link
}
```

Comment: What is the **exact type** of `fileContentResult` ? (The runtime type, not the static-type, so don't say `IActionResult`, because that's an interface type)

Comment: @Dai Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult or to be exact Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult>